# vaadin form validation?

Tags: css, vaadin

I have a form in vaadin with some textfields which are required. When I click on a submit button, it validates the textfields..
When a field is not valid, it will have red border..

```
if(!field.isValid()) {
    valid = false;
    field.setStyleName("error"); 
}
```

Now my problem:

When I click in the textfield the border turns back to dark blue and when I click out of the field it becomes red again.

How can I make sure that when you click in the textfield, the border remains red?
Anybody has an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try adding `!important` in the end of the border color declaration, ie. `border-color: red !important;`. You can then check with firebug whether the style will remain in the field.